# In Gimp, how can I *throw away* outside transparent pixels?

Tags: gimp

In Photshop, if I copy a portion of an image with surrounding transparent pixels and paste it into a new canvas, it will have the outside transparent pixels removed, resulting in a tight canvas containing only the outer bounding box.

Can I do the same thing in Gimp?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the menus: Image> Autocrop Image

piece of cake.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't find that. And I did have a decent dig in the menus.

Comment: It's not actually descriptively named, and it seems too good to be true :-) When was image manipulation ever that easy?

Comment: If $deity had wanted image editing to be obvious and simple, they wouldn't have given us GIMP

Comment: I believe this is now: Image > Fit Canvas to Layers for Gimp 2.10.8.

Comment: Image --> Crop to content now

Answer (score 11):

Image > Crop to Content
(Version GIMP 2.10.12)

Comment: Layer -> Crop to Content ... will also work for layers :)

Answer (score 2):

As of GIMP 2.10.14 the menu would be Image > Zealous Crop